# sudo apachectl -k start not work on MacOS HIGH SIERRA

Tags: macos, apache, httpd.conf

I've run **sudo apachectl -k start** , but the httpd process wasn't created.
And when I've run **apachectl configtest** on terminal, it shows me *Syntax OK*.
Also I run other commands:

> sudo apachectl -k restart  => httpd not running, trying to start.
>
> sudo apachectl -k stop => httpd (pid 1369?) not running

More info about apache error_log file:  **LogLevel debug**

```
[Mon Nov 27 01:15:00.390588 2017] [unique_id:info] [pid 1572] AH01566: using ip addr 192.***.*.**
[Mon Nov 27 01:15:01.004998 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 1572] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Mon Nov 27 01:15:01.008629 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 1572] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.25 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.25, Library: OpenSSL/1.0.2j
[Mon Nov 27 01:15:01.046466 2017] [unique_id:info] [pid 1574] AH01566: using ip addr 192.***.**.*
[Mon Nov 27 01:15:02.000248 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1574] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Mon Nov 27 01:15:02.000473 2017] [ssl:info] [pid 1574] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've just updated the apache using brew. Then I configured my apache again and now everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have replaced the default ruby.

Open you terminal and enter:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

It works for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, looks like `apachectl` is somehow broken after *High Sierra* update. Right now the solution for me is to control Apache daemon directly by `launchctl`:

```
sudo launchctl kickstart -r system/org.apache.httpd
```